# Can't display pictures in the gallery (Android 10+)

Tags: java, android, android-mediascanner

I'm currently having a problem with making my pictures contained in the app/files/Picture folder appear in the gallery with a device running Android 10. I created a folder in Picture called "ticket" (for sorting purposes) and I'm trying to display the entire folder in the gallery.

The following code works perfectly fine with a device running Android 9, but I just can't manage to make it work with the other device.

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
File dir = new File(currentDirPath); // currentDirPath = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.app_test_emasolar/files/Pictures/ticket
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(dir);
mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);}
```

I also tried to add

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

to the manifest but nothing changed, I'm still stuck.

Any ideas?

Comment: `currentPhotoPath` ?? Please start your code with showning/assigning the exact value of that path.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, here's the path : "Android/data/com.example.app_test_emasolar/files/Pictures/ticket" . ticket is a folder I created in Pictures for sorting purposes. I'm trying to make the entire folder containing all my pictures appear in the gallery. I updated the post.

Comment: You are using an app specific path/directory and the media store will not scan your files there. Such files will never be indexed and hence not shown by Gallery apps. A bit of privacy you can say. It should not be possible on an Android 9 device either.

Comment: `I'm trying to make the entire folder containing all my pictures appear in the gallery.` I dont know if you can let the media store scan folders in that way. Anyhow that folder will never be scanned as it is apps specific folder.

Comment: Do you know how i could fix that? I've seen something about "scoped storage".

Comment: You use scoped storage. Save them at another place. In public DCIM or Pictures directory for example.